# Apache Axis Custom TrustManager

Tags: ssl, apache-axis, truststore

I would like to assign a custom trust manager to a specific org.apache.axis.client.Call.  With regular HTTP clients in Java I would just create an SSLContext and the TrustManager.

Is this possible somehow in Apache Axis?

Answer (score 3):

This is very possible in Apache Axis, and you are spot on when you thought to create a custom SSLContext and TrustManager.  You can create a class which implements the Axis SecureSocketFactory interface and define a create() method which will return a custom Socket.  Before you invoke your call, you have to tell Axis that you want to use this custom socket factory with the following line of code:

```
AxisProperties.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory", "com.ade.martini.YourSecureSocketFactory");
```

After that, you can invoke your Axis call as usual:

```
Service service = new Service();
Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
// set your endpoint, operation, etc.
call.invoke(...);
```

Here is what the class `YourSecureSocketFactory` might look like:

```
package com.ade.martini;

import org.apache.axis.components.net.BooleanHolder;
import org.apache.axis.components.net.SecureSocketFactory;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class YourSecureSocketFactory implements SecureSocketFactory {

    private String KEYSTORE_TYPE = "JKS";
    private String PROTOCOL = "SSL";
    private String ALGORITHM = "SunX509";
    private int DEFAULT_PORT = 443;

    protected SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = null;
    private String keystoreFile;
    private String keystorePass;
    private KeyStore kstore = null;

    public AxisSecureSocketFactory(Hashtable attributes) {
    }

    public Socket create(String host, int port, StringBuffer otherHeaders, BooleanHolder useFullURL)
            throws Exception {

        if (sslFactory == null) initFactory();

        if (port<=0) port = DEFAULT_PORT;
        Socket sslSocket = sslFactory.createSocket(host, port);
        return sslSocket;
    }

    protected void initFactory() throws IOException {

        /* One way to find certificates */
        keystoreFile = "yourkeystore.jks";
        keystorePass = "password";

        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = getContext();
            sslFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof IOException) {
                throw (IOException) e;
            }
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /* this method will accept all certificates and therefore should NOT
       be used in most production settings */
    private TrustManager[ ] getTrustManagers() {
        TrustManager[ ] certs = new TrustManager[ ] {
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[ ] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[ ] certs, String t) { }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[ ] certs, String t) { }
                }
        };
        return certs;
    }

    protected SSLContext getContext() throws Exception {

        kstore = initKeyStore(keystoreFile, keystorePass);
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        kmf.init(kstore, keystorePass.toCharArray());
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(PROTOCOL);
        sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
        return (sslContext);
    }

    private KeyStore initKeyStore(String keystoreFile, String keystorePass)
            throws IOException {
        try {
            KeyStore kstore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE);
            ClassLoader classLoader = YourSecureSocketFactory.class.getClassLoader();
            File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(keystoreFile).getFile());
            InputStream istream = new FileInputStream(file);
            kstore.load(istream, keystorePass.toCharArray());
            return kstore;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            throw fnfe;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw ioe;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new IOException("Exception trying to load keystore " + keystoreFile + ": " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

If you place a breakpoint in the `create()` method you will notice that it gets executed when you invoke an Axis call.  Seeing this code being executed is confirmation that Axis is using your custom socket along with the custom TrustManager we defined.

Please take note that the TrustManager I used in the example code will accept **all** certificates coming from the server.  This usually isn't the behavior you want in production.

Comment: I guess the default constructeur should be : public YourSecureSocketFactory (Hashtable attributes) {}
Nevertheless, your example is working good and helped me :)